# LDAPs Query from Active directory

Tags: php, ldap

The goal is to connect a HTML Page with php to an Active directory.
The Active Directory is only accessable from the System Admin.
So i would have to make a Bind with the Credentials of the Sysadmin and then make a query inside the active directory with the Credentials of the users.

Is that right?

So here is the Code with the i tried to bind with the User Credentials. But it alwasys gives the Echo from Else back "Invalid Credential".

```
<?php

$ldap_dn = "CN=".$_POST["username"].",OU=EUTM,OU=Users,OU=HQ,OU=ULTIMATE,DC=ultimate,DC=local";
$ldap_password = $_POST["password"];

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldaps://192.168.124.40:636");
ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST["username"];

    header("Location: Startseite.php");

    }

else
    {
    echo "Invalid Credential";
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

New Code

```
<?php

$ldap_dn = "CN=sysadmin";
$ldap_password = "123456";

$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldaps://192.168.124.40:636");
ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
{
    echo "King"

    }

else
    {
    echo "Invalid Credential";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `$ldap_dn` and `$ldap_password` are used for binding, so those credentials must refer to the System Admin / ldap manager. Then, once bound to the server, you would check the user credentials by searching the ldap tree for such user and, if found, check his password.

Comment: Also, check the ldap connection itself `if ($ldap_con) { /* ldap_bind() ... */ } else { echo 'Could not connect to LDAP server'}`

Comment: Thanks for your comments
So i added the code above

Comment: ok it can't bind

Comment: If it i the sysadmin do i still use the "CN=" in front ?

Comment: sysadmin must be registered in ldap, you need to bind with its dn. Did you check the connection ?

Comment: Yes there is the problem. This is the Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server    but i know that the server supports Ldaps because it has already be done in an other project

Comment: Did you try to replace `192.168.124.40` with the server's hostname ? In your LDAP server's certificate, there should be a _subject_ containing a `CN=<hostname>`.

Comment: If i put in the hostname can i also add the port 636 to it ?
so i can make an ldaps